# PostGIS St_AsMVT latitude incorrect at low zoom levels

Tags: postgis, vector-tiles

I'm using the St_AsMVT feature in Post GIS to create mapbox tiles.

This works ok at high zoom levels (>9) but at lower levels the latitude appears to be significantly off...which gets worse as the zoom level decreases.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is it a bug in PostGIS? In the GIF the red box should stay in it's original position, but moves north in lower zoom level tiles.

[image: PostGIS created vector tiles displayed in mapbox]

Comment: I think this is a projection issue. My data is in ESPG 4326. I have tried transforming to 3857 but it does not seem to be valid geometry. It is as though the tiles generated are not projected correctly?

Comment: How do you set the bounds of the tiles in your query?

Comment: @user30184 I'm using mapbox sphericalmercator (https://github.com/mapbox/sphericalmercator). I was previously using mapnik to create the tiles using a similar method which was working ok with the mapnik generated tiles

Comment: I switched to a different method of creating the tile bounds (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jawg/blog-resources/master/how-to-make-mvt-with-postgis/bbox.sql) and used St_Transform to convert from ESPG 4326 to 3857 and now the position is correct. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I switched to a different method of creating the tile bounds (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jawg/blog-resources/master/how-to-make-mvt-with-postgis/bbox.sql) and used St_Transform to convert from ESPG 4326 to 3857 and now the position is correct. Thanks for the suggestion